# Arabic encoding

Tags: java, jsp, arabic

I have a simple web application which consists of Servlets and JSPs. In one JSP, data is entered to be sent to a Servlet where the Servlet interacts with the back-end to save data in a DB (MySQL).

My problem is that the data is in Arabic, hence i set the page directive with the UTF-8 encoding and added a filter to set both request and response encoding to utf-8 but i still get rubbish data from the JSP to the Servlet.

Note that I am using Apache Tomcat Server v6.0, do you have any idea where is my problem ?

Comment: Might be a problem with the HTML form. Can you post the code for that? Also, have you confirmed that the problem is not with the database? Try this: put a hard-coded Arabic string into your Java code, save that to the DB, and see if it gets garbled.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Tomcat uses `ISO-8859-1` character encoding when decoding URLs received from a browser. You have to make sure that your tomcat's server.xml's file connector element has URIEncoding attribute which value is `UTF-8`:

```
<Connector port="8080" 
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Take a look [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+Tomcat%27s+URI+encoding) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the text is being saved to the database as unicode, not strings.  Then encode it as utf-8 when you display it.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to: Program -> neatbans -> neatbeans.config, then add this line in it:
`netbeans_default_options=" .... -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

2- Go to console of server (glassfish) -> Configurations -> server-config -> JVM Option -> Add Jvm option, then add this:
`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  and save`

3- Change host of the dataset to:
`<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chokrbd?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>`

More deatils in this blog  https://android-dev-go.blogspot.com/